# div height 100% inside td wrong computed in ie and opera

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, opera

I am trying to create a **header-container layout**. The header height is variable and the container should always fill the rest of space (width, height).

**IE (9,10) and latest Opera** computes the height of the layout table wrong so as scroll bars appear. The rest of the browsers computes it right (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).

```
<div class="header-container-layout">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="layout-hdr">
        <td style="background:#aaa">
            asdasdas asdasd 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="layout-content" >
        <td style="height:100%;">
            <div class="layout-content-inner" style="background:#ccc;">


            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


.header-container-layout{
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.layout-content-inner{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

You can see here the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/95und/9/

Is there a solution for this *without javascript* ?

Thanks!

EDIT: My problem does not have to do with scroll bars appearence, I could avoid them with overflow:hidden. The problem is that I want to position content absolute to the bottom of the container.

Comment: hmm, considering this further, I'm looking at a table-based layout with inline styles... How tied are you to that specific markup?

Comment: I am open for ideas !

Answer (score 1):

Well, adding `overflow:hidden` to the `.header-container-layout` makes the scrollbar go away in Opera:

```
.header-container-layout{
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    ***overflow:hidden;***
}
```

I can't actually test on IE terribly easily right now but I suspect it would probably behave the same.

The only problem with this, of course, is that if your content *is* particularly long, it could get cut off. Depends what your plans are I guess.

http://jsfiddle.net/yochannah/95und/10/

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I could add overflow:hidden but I want to absolute position content inside the container and that will be hidden in any case. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/95und/12/

Comment: @GeorgeMavritsakis Ah, ok... and I'm guessing that since you say the header height is variable, you can't do a negative margin sticky footer trick like http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I am afraid not. Actually, currently I have implemented the header-container layout with javascript and absolute positioning, so as when header height changes I recompute positions. I am looking for a more elegant way that will automatically handle header size changes.